# just what is the origin in cocos2d boundingBox

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

So I have a CGRect and it has a size and a CGpoint call origin.  Is origin the center of the square or the top left?

Comment: Why not just to check it yourself using some image with known dimensions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The CGRect defines how far the bounding box extends along each axis from the origin point, so it will never be the center.

However, cocos2D has a default coordinate system where the origin is the bottom-left of the view, so the origin in this case would be the bottom-left of the box.